# Use conditional constraint or normalize table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have two entities: `A` and `B`. The latter has two types `B1` and `B2`. Their relationship is:

1. `(A,B1)` is `(1:1)`
2. `(A,B2)` is `(1,N)`

When creating database tables, I wonder how is the best way to guarantee consistency. I can see two options: (1) Create one table and use a **conditional constraint** that swaps the consistency strategy based on `B` type or (2) create **two tables**, one per `B` type, and set each consistency strategy separately.

---

A note on the table usage:

- The RMDBS is PostgreSQL;
- The `read` operations are much bigger than the `write` operations;
- The `write` operations of `B2` are much bigger than the `write` operations of `B1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it is better to normalise, unless there is a strong reason not to (like performance issues).

If both B1 and B2 must share a unique ID sequence (b_id), that can only be done within a single table: B. If they can have separate ID sequences (b1_id, b2_id), it will probably be easier to create separate tables: B1, B2.